# Mutations to trigger a promise

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm trying to figure out how I might be able to adopt Apollo in my React Native project compared to RXJS & Redux.

One of the special things about this app is that data mutations are not done through a traditional API but through Blockchain based transactions. Therefore I cannot simply call mutate in Apollo and expect it to eventually mutate something on the database as it's gonna go to a completely different several using a completely different library.

Would it be possible to have some kind of middleware which intercepted a mutation request and redirected it to another async library to get the job done? I'm wondering if `apollo-link` might be the way to do it.

Comment: Are you considering setting up a GraphQL server and calling the library server-side, or is this something you're doing client-side?

Comment: No this is something client side.